# Magento: Error getting product collection by category

Tags: zend-framework, magento

I'm trying to get a product collection with a category filter that takes the category as an object. The problem is I'm getting the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in
>   /var/www/vhosts/officeaccounts/subdomains/ls/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Collection.php
>   on line 557

When I comment out the category filter it don't get the errors.

It's saying that I'm not passing in an object. But yet I can still access the getId() method of the object by doing `var_dump($category->getId());` This returns the id as a string.

```
$category = Mage::registry('current_category');
if (!$category) {
    $product = $this->getProduct();
    $cats = $product->getCategoryIds();
    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cats[0]);
}

function getFallbackItems() {
    $productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                    ->addCategoryFilter($category);
    $productCollection->getSelect()->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('RAND()'));
    return $productCollection;
}
```

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: In your test, is $category getting assigned by the first line (Mage::registry) or by the Mage::getModel line? What version of Magento are you using, because in Enterprise 1.10.0.1 the file in your error list doesn't exist. Makes me assume it is a newer 1.6 version that uses the new database abstractions. Which means you may have found a bug.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for replying. Yeah so if you get to a product (this code is on related products phtml) through the search page the current category isn't known. So what I'm doing is checking to see if the $category exists and if not I'll reset it by getting one of it's parents. Yeah Magento ver. 1.6.0.0

Answer (score 0):

If the last if else block of function addAttributeToFilter() of Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection try this code

```
    elseif(is_string($attribute) && $attribute == 'category_ids'){

        if(isset($condition['eq'])){
            $this->getSelect()->join(
            array('category' => $this->getTable('catalog/category_product')),
            'category.product_id=e.entity_id AND category.category_id='.$condition['eq'],
            array()
            );
        }
        return $this;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the product collection by category, do the following :

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(12);
$productCollection = $category->getProductCollection();
$productCollection->getSelect()->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('RAND()'));
print_r($productCollection->getData());
```

Note: here **12** is the category_id

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues with your code:

1. You should register the category (current_category) in case it does not exist.
2. I don't see the declaration of the variable $category any where in your function getFallbackItems (I suppose you are following the OOP coding).
   So sure you will get the error when you use the filter addCategoryFilter($category)
3. You should always check the exist of the variable before using it.

====>

So the code can be improved as below:

```
$category = Mage::registry('current_category');

if (!$category) {
    $product = $this->getProduct();
    $cats = $product->getCategoryIds();
    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cats[0]);
    Mage:register('current_category', $category);
}

// Suppose it will be called somewhere
function getFallbackItems() {
    $category = Mage::registry('current_category');
    $productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

    if ($category && $category->getId()) {
        $productCollection->addCategoryFilter($category);
    }

    $productCollection->getSelect()->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('RAND()'));

    return $productCollection;
}
```